# EntityFunction.DiffDays Causes This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, linq

Its me trying to convert an SQL Query to a LINQuery

```
,case when  DATEDIFF(day, isnull(a.NewWorkerDate,a.Workerdate), a.Workerdate)=0 then 
    'NEWWORKER' ELSE 'OLDWORKER' End as WorkerType
```

Tried with a different set of Linq:

```
var checkNewDateValue = a.NewWorkerDate!= null ? a.NewWorkerDate: appInfo.Workerdate;
var datedifference = EntityFunctions.DiffDays(checkHiredDateValue, a.Workerdate);
```

but produces an error like below :

> Exception: System.NotSupportedException: This function can only be
>   invoked from LINQ to Entities.

Comment: Please show your full linq code?

Answer (score 0):

`EntityFunctions` provides you with linq functions that cannot be called outside linq statements. However you can use `DateTime.Subtract` method:

```
var datedifference = checkHiredDateValue.Subtract(a.Workerdate).Days;
```

Note that if `checkHiredDateValue` or `a.Workerdate` are `DateTime?` first you need to cast them to `DateTime`.
Sidenote: `EntityFunctions` is obsolete, use `System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.DiffDays` instead.